# Getstream - Pin an activity in a timeline feed to list pinned posts at the top of the feed

Tags: getstream-io

In Getstream, how do I pin an activity so that the pinned activities are listed in the timeline feed first?

Answer (score 1):

You can come up with many different score functions and here is one of them:

```
{"score": "decay_linear(time) + is_pinned", "defaults": {"is_pinned": 0}}
```

By default, activities are ranked according to their time since `is_pinned` is zero.
When you want to pin activities, you need to update them to have custom `is_pinned` field to have `1` which will take them upper in ranking.